# Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM OrganizationWebProxyClient is null Error when trying to connect to Dynamic365 using C#

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm

I am trying to connect to Dynamics 365 using C# code.

Here is my code for the connection logic:

```
public static CrmServiceClient InitializeClient(string connstr)
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    var crmclient = new CrmServiceClient(connstr);

    // ERROR IS THROWN IF CONNECTION FAILS
    if (!crmclient.IsReady)
    {
        throw new Exception(crmclient.LastCrmError);
    }

    return crmclient;
}
```

I am using Microsoft Dynamics365 version 8.2.

Here is the connection string:

```
AuthType=Office365;Server=https://compagny.name/organizationname; Domain=domain; Username=username; Password=password
```

But I always get the following error:

> Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM OrganizationWebProxyClient is null

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Showing `Exceptions` with `Inner Exception` & `Stacktrace` contains tons of information without it it's a guessing game as to what went wrong. Kindly add the full Exception for these kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Office365 authentication. It relies on WS-Trust and the ADFS configuration on your company network may cause an issue here.

WS-Trust is no longer recommended. Switch over to using an OAuth based connection string.

See [Use of Office365 authentication with Microsoft Dataverse - MS Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/authenticate-office365-deprecation) and this announcement: [Deprecation of Office365 authentication type and OrganizationServiceProxy class for connecting to Dataverse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/important-changes-coming#deprecation-of-office365-authentication-type-and-organizationserviceproxy-class-for-connecting-to-dataverse).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use OAuth auth type instead of Office365. Here is an example of mine C# console app that provides a ServiceClient to communicate with Dynamics.

```
 var connectionString = "AuthType=OAuth;Username=your@user.name;Password=yourpassword;Url=urlToDynamicsInstance";
                        
 return new ServiceClient(connectionString);
```

ServiceClient is available in Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client library.

Here is a full example of how I use it in my app:

```
 static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddTransient<IOrganizationService>(serviceProvider =>
                    {
                        var connectionString = "AuthType=OAuth;Username=your@user.name;Password=yourpassword;Url=urlToDynamicsInstance";

                        return new ServiceClient(connectionString);
                    });
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method

```
string connString = "AuthType=Office365;Url=https:yourorg.api.crm4.dynamics.com/;Username=username;Password=password;";

        CrmServiceClient service = new CrmServiceClient(connString);
```

Make sure to write ; for every field.